How can I map /mnt/**/* with updatedb to work with (p)locate?
When I use the locate command (specifically plocate 1.1.22), it doesn't seem to include any files under the /mnt directory, i.e. on external drives.
The man page for updatedb claims "The whole file system is scanned by default" (which I take to mean /**/*), so I retried after an update, but no luck.
I considered creating a symlink to /mnt in a place that updatedb does map, but I understand from this Q&A that symlinks won't work by default.
I also tried setting PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS = "no" and removing /mnt from PRUNEPATHS in /etc/updatedb.conf, but again this did nothing.
So, is there a way to make updatedb or locate work with files under /mnt?

There is also PRUNEFS which might exclude the filesystem type you have mounted, eg iso9660, cifs, nfs4.

That worked for me, thanks! @meuh
